# Is it possible to know the maximum number accepted by chr using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

From the Python's documentation of the [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#chr) built-in function, the maximum value that `chr` accepts is 1114111 (in decimal) or 0x10FFFF (in base 16). And in fact

```
>>> chr(1114112)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    chr(1114112)
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)
```

My first question is the following, why exactly that number? The second question is: if this number changes, is it possible to know from a Python command the maximum value accepted by `chr`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`sys.maxunicode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxunicode):

> An integer giving the value of the largest Unicode code point, i.e. `1114111` (`0x10FFFF` in hexadecimal).

On my Python 2.7 UCS-2 build the maximum Unicode character supported by `unichr()` is 0xFFFF:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxunicode
65535
```

but Python 3.3 and newer switched to a new internal storage format for Unicode strings, and the maximum is now *always* `0x10FFFF`. See [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/).

`0x10FFFF` is the maximum Unicode codepoint as defined in the Unicode standard. Quoting the [Wikipedia article on Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Architecture_and_terminology):

> Unicode defines a codespace of 1,114,112 code points in the range 0 to 10FFFF.

Comment: And the difference between Wikipedia's `1114112` and Python's doc of `1114111` is because Python starts from `0`, hence the shift by one?

Comment: @Andrejs - Its because Unicode counts from zero, not python specifically. There are 1114112 code points ranging from 0 to 1114111.