# How to get the maximal unicode value in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

In a Python console, I obtain as expected:

```
>>> chr(0x10ffff)
'\U0010ffff'
>>> chr(0x110000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)
```

In [this table](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/) which provides all the unicodes, the maximal used value (not reserved) is 0xE01EF, and with reserved ones 0x10FFFF. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52203351) explains reasons why the maximal value is 0x10FFFF, but in order to design a code that can adapt to unicode standard evolution, how can I get this maximal value? Is there an existing module that provides it?

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52203351

Comment: `the maximal usable value (not reserved) is 0xE01EF` this is simply wrong. Those are the *assigned* code points, and more will be assigned later

Comment: F0000—FFFFF Supplementary Private Use Area-A, 
100000—10FFFF Supplementary Private Use Area-B

Comment: @Corralien, I have put this information in my question already. My question is how to get this maximum value in Python, something like `get_last_unicode_val()`. So in my opinion, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I reopened the question. Maybe @phuclv can answer to your question.

Comment: yep, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813535/is-it-possible-to-know-the-maximum-number-accepted-by-chr-using-python) does, and my question is a duplicate of it. Nice catch, thanks @Corralien